# reading from csv file and do computation and save in a new csv file (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

This may be a very simple question but I cannot find a solution for it.
I have three csv files with specific names, let's say (A, B, C), each file have one column named as a score. Each csv file is read and the corresponding feature is computed by a function like my_func() then I am going to save each file in a new csv file with the file name and the corresponding feature value which is calculated by my_func(). The desired output looks like this:

```
user_id      sd 
A           output of my_func()
B           output of my_func()
C           output of my_func()
```

I iterated through each file to read the data and then do my computation with my_func() function and then return the value from the function and add the values to the columns sd and user_id in each iteration.

here is snipped of my code:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(path)
data_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sd','user_id'])

def my_funct(data, user_id):
   computing sd ....
   data_new.sd = value of sd
   data_new.user_id = value of file name

   return sd

for file_name in allFiles:
       data_ = pd.read_csv(filename)
       sd, user_id = my_function(data_, user_id_)
```

with this solution, I just got the last value of my function as follow:

```
user_id       sd   
C           output of my_func()
```

Comment: Pandas is probably overkill for this, you could use `csv` and get a dict of each file then do your calculations on that.

Comment: @CMMCD would you please explain more detail!

Comment: If you can provide some sample files with the same format as your real data and expected output I can give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in my_func you are overwriting a single entry in data_new. Instead of

```
data_new.sd = value of sd
data_new.user_id = value of file name
```

try using the append method as follows:

```
data_new = data_new.append({'sd' : VALUE OF SD , 'user_id' : VALUE OF FILE NAME}, ignore_index=True)
```

Further documentation here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Here's a sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sd','user_id'])
print(data_new)
data_new = data_new.append({'sd' : 'test' , 'user_id' : 'working'}, ignore_index=True)
print(data_new)
data_new = data_new.append({'sd' : 'test2' , 'user_id' : 'still working'}, ignore_index=True)
print(data_new)

data_new.to_csv("U:\Random\pandasTest.csv")
```

Comment: the result would be empty!

Comment: @Elham why would it be empty?

Comment: I dont know! I executed the code and the final csv file is empty!

Comment: @Elham did you write to the csv? data_new.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv')

Comment: @Elham I added some test code at the end of my answer- try it and change the file path for your CSV. you should see that the dataframe is updated each time with append and the to_csv method writes your df to a file. Are you doing each of those steps?